# I don't understand how reputation works

Tags: support, specific-question, reputation, voting

There's [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17696609/bella-games) with one closed question with a score of zero and 27 reputation. I clearly don't understand how reputation works. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Visit the user's reputation page for details: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17696609/bella-games?tab=reputation

Comment: Visit the [whats-reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) help page for explanations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty easy math on the question.  It has 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes, which results in a total of 24 net reputation.

[image]

It's increasingly likely that the first vote on the question was a downvote, which wouldn't count against the score (if they had no other rep gain), so it'd have an *effective* value of +3/-2, or 26 total reputation.

Comment: You should explain and show the exact math: `+3*(10 per upvote) - 3*(-2 per downvote) = (3*10) - (3*2) = 30 - 6 = 24`

Comment: @ughStackExchange:  That'd be a suitable edit to make if you wanted to :)

Comment: @user16320675 it's 1000 rep to see the vote breakdown.